# How is alternative if we cant use ng-checked with ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

As I have a list of item and I want to bind them to ng-checked, I can use ng-checked to check them but it doesn't work with ng-model then what is the alternative solution for an item to be checked and bind to ng-model.

```
$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];
$scope.selecteditems = ['item2', 'item3'];

<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="{{item.item_id}}" ng-false-value="'0'" ng-checked="isItemExist(item.item_id)" ng-model="groupItems[item.item_id]" > {{item.item_desc}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-value-true` to tell angular that your ng-model is a string.

I could only get ng-true-value working if I added the extra quotes like so (as shown in the official Angular docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

```
ng-true-value="'1'"
```

Comment: i am using ng-true value the problem is how to check it and bind it to ng-model.

Comment: In angularjs doc they give example

Comment: i have done this part this is how my ng-true-value will be bind to ng-model, but what in update case as i have a item currently and how i will make a checkbox checked which will bind to ng-model.